# How can you read the stdout from a continously streaming python file in C++ Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, python-2.7, visual-studio-2012, popen

Right now I am using C++ to gather joint data from the kinect. I am clustering this data into different clusters using python Anaconda libraries.  I sent the joint data to the python script by using python's popen function.

Now I need to send the cluster data back to C++.  This is what I have tried so far:

```
char psBuffer[128];
FILE *pPipe;

if ((pPipe = _popen("python cluster_predictor.py", "rt")) == NULL) {
    exit(1);
}

while (fgets(psBuffer, 128, pPipe)) {
    printf(psBuffer);
}
```

However, this does not work because I cannot read the pipe until the python script terminates, which it never does.

How can I read the output from the python script continously without having to wait for the script to finish using _popen (or something else)?

Comment: In C++, use `std::cout` unless you have good reason to do otherwise. Also, have you tried flushing the console buffer?

Comment: My python script never finishes running. It is continously getting data from the Kinect. I can only print after the python file terminates. I need to save the data as it is being sent to the terminal